# Why electrical switches are rated lower for led than incadescent lights?

Tags: electrical, switch

I bought a dimmer that supports ic, halogen, led and cfl lights.
It says 600w for incadescent and halogen and 150w for led and cfl.
Why is the difference? 
What happens if I put it in a circuit with 8 led lights rated at 25w?

Comment: This question is probably best answered on http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ as it is the electronic behavior of LEDs which challenges the dimmer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a switch, for one thing. It's a dimmer - a switch, in the same circumstances, would be just fine with full rated amperage of LED or CFL. Unless you have a great deal of interest in dimming, your best option if you have 200W of LEDs on the circuit would be to use a switch.

The limit comes from the interaction of the power supply circuits internal to "dimmable" LEDs/CFLs and the dimmers that can be used with them. Overloading the dimmer will probably cost you at least a new dimmer, and depending what fails, perhaps one or more of the attached lights.

[Look at the bottom of page 15:](http://www.lutron.com/en-US/Education-Training/Documents/Controlling%20LEDs%20webinar.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the reference. So They say that leds take lot more current at startup and at peaks. Hopefully I can stick with 13W bulbs.